# How to reference code behind variable in ASPX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm not sure why when referencing a code behind variable in an asp.net control, I get the text of the reference:

```
<%=this.Person.Contact.Emails[0].EmailAddress%>
```

This outputs the literal reference text:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" Text="<%=this.Person.Contact.Emails[0].EmailAddress%>"></asp:TextBox>
```

This renders the variable value:

```
<input id="testfield" type="text" value="<%=this.Person.Contact.Emails[0].EmailAddress%>" />
```

Any ideas how I can get the variable value in the asp.net control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say:

```
EmailAddress.Text = this.Person.Contact.Emails[0].EmailAddress
```

in your code behind

Comment: This page doesn't have any code behind.  I'm trying to avoid putting code in the aspx and code behind.  The reference is a code behind but originates in another class.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the solution in Code Behind in hunter's solution but another option would be to use data binding with #:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" Text="<%# this.Person.Contact.Emails[0].EmailAddress%>" />
```

But then you have to bind the server control in code-behind:

```
EmailAdress.DataBind();
```

The = sign is like a call to `Response.Write()` at this place and just outputs whatever follows as text.

Comment: Ok, there are solutions and I didn't asked the question correctly.  Instead of "how", I should have asked "why".

Comment: WHY you can get the variable value in the asp.net control? Is that really your question? TIf the question is not correct, please fix it, I don't understand it right now.